# How can I debug chromium in visual studio 2019?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, chromium, visual-studio-debugging

Visual studio crashes while building **all.sln**. I have all the source files. Chrome.exe is also working fine. But, It's been a week, I am not able to build chromium from Visual Studio. It shows this **error** **message**.

> Unable to start program* **allocator_clang_newlib_x64**. *The system can not find the file specified*.

Comment: Did you set the correct project as startup project? Make sure that all of the needed files are compiled before debugging.

Comment: Yes, that way I am able to run chrome.exe but that's not what I want. I want to debug/make changes to the code and see how it takes effect.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Build Chromium from Visual Studio and debug too? The recommended way to build Chromium is to build from CLI using `ninja`

Comment: I've build chromium from ninja and now I want to debug the source code. Also, I want to ask how can I see the changes I made in the source code. Do, I have to build it everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `all.sln` is a very big solution with all the Chromium source code as Visual C++ projects. It will make Visual Studio slow even on high end machine. So the recommended way to debug your Chromium fork is via a standalone Visual Studio project. You can follow the steps below:

1. Open Visual Studio command prompt
2. Navigate to your Chromium's `src` folder from that CLI
3. Open Visual Studio to debug your Chromium executable by typing the following `devenv /DEBUGEXE "out\YourBuildFolder\chrome.exe"`
4. Press `F5` to start debugging your source code.

Tip: If you want to start debugging by stopping at the entry point, on **Solution Explorer** pane, right click that project and choose `Debug` -> `Step into new instance` from the context menu.

You can use `all.sln` to edit the source code and yes you have to compile it again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!Still when I run all.sln on the local Machine Debugger. These errors pop up: toolchain.ninja:40627: loading 'obj/net/backoff_entry_serializer_fuzzer_input.ninja': The system cannot find the path specified. allocator_clang_newlib_x64                         MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C build\src\new\Default\  clang_newlib_x64/obj/base/allocator/allocator.stamp" exited with code 1. allocator_clang_newlib_x64 build\src\new\Default\clang_newlib_x64\obj\base\allocator\allocator_clang_newlib_x64.vcxproj 53

Comment: Try running `gclient sync`  and then generate a new VS project again.

Comment: Still,the same error.

Comment: My configuring settings are:                                                   
**Solution configuration: GN                                                                                 
 Solution platform: x64                                                                                      Debugger : Local Windows Debugger**